# Sentence meaning similarity in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, sentence-similarity

I want to calculate the sentence meaning similarity. I am using cosine similarity but this method does not fulfill my needs.

For example, if I have these two sentences.

1. He and his father are very close.
2. He shares a wonderful bond with his father.

What I need is calculating the similarity between these sentences based on the meaning similarity and not just matching similar words

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This falls under paraphrasing. check this useful link,
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers#quick-tour-tf-20-training-and-pytorch-interoperability

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/similar-sentences/ try this

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to represent each word using pre-trained word vectors ("embeddings"). These are vectors with a few hundred dimensions where words with similar meaning (e.g., "close", "bond") should have similar vectors. The key idea is that word embeddings could represent that the two sentences have similar meaning even though they use different words.

- This could be done quickly in a package such as Spacy in python. See https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity
- Common pre-trained vectors include the Google news word embeddings (https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors) and GLOVE embeddings (https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/).

Here's a simple approach: represent each word by its pretrained embedding and average words across the sentence. Now compare the vectors using any reasonable distance measure (cosine is standard).